# Tkinter? Error converting string to integer?

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm new to tkinter. I'm trying to make a currency converter but when i try to convert the entry to a float(to convert to different currency ) i get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\New folder (3)\converter.py", line 40, in convert
money = float( money.get() )
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

This is my code: 
    import tkinter
    from tkinter import *

```
root=tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Currency Converter')
root.minsize(300,300)
root.geometry('500x500')


def convert():
nw= Toplevel()
nw.title('Convert')
nw.minsize(300,300)
nw.geometry('400x400')
am= Label(nw,text='Please enter the amount of money you have')
money= Entry(nw, width=5)
ra= Label(nw, text='Please enter the exchange rate')
rate= Entry(nw,width=6)
convert= Label(nw,text='You have')
con= tkinter.Button(nw, text='Convert')
b= tkinter.Button(nw, text= str(money))
am.pack()
money.pack()
ra.pack()
rate.pack()
convert.pack()
con.pack()
b.pack()
money = float( money.get() )



welcome= Label(root,text='Welcome to Currency Converter, please select the conversion you wish to              use')
pe= tkinter.Button(root, text='Pound - Euro', command=convert)
ep= tkinter.Button(root, text='Euro - Pound', command=convert)

welcome.pack()
pe.pack()
ep.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: The solution here should solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886812/tkinter-entry-widget-and-variables

Comment: Have you thought to see what `money.get()` is returning to see if it's what you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to explain why this problem occurs is to go through what is happening step-by-step:

1. The main window is built.
2. The user clicks either the `pe` button or the `ep` button.
3. The `convert` function, which each button is hooked up to, is invoked.
4. The function runs through to this line: `money = float( money.get() )`.
5. Since the user hasn't entered anything yet, `money.get()` returns an empty string.  Empty strings cannot be made into floats, so a `ValueError` is thrown.

So, summed up, the problem is that you are not adding any safeties for if `money.get` returns a string that cannot be converted into a float (i.e. an empty string, a string with letters in it, etc.).

---

You can create a safety like this:

```
try:
    money = float(money.get())
except ValueError:
    pass
```

or, like this:

```
money = money.get()
if money.isdigit():
    money = float(money)
```

Regardless of how you choose to solve this problem, you need to do *something* for when the return value of `money.get` cannot be converted into a float.